# No Public Key for Libffi-devel

Tags: redhat, rpm, libffi

I'm trying to install some files I pulled into an offline system, but I am missing a key file.

When I try to do

`sudo yum localinstall libffi-devel-3.0.13-19.el7.x86_64.rpm`

I am met with error

`warning: /opt/libffi-devel-3.0.13-19.el7.x86_64.rpm : Header V3 RSA/SHA256 Signature id fd431d51: NOKEY. Public key for libffi-devel-3.0.13-19.el7.x86_64.rpm is not installed.`

However looking around I cannot find where you're supposed to obtain and install this key from. Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

On this [page](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/rpm-gpg-verify-packages) you can find RedHat instructions how to deal with signs of RPM packages.

And the message above is a warning. You can get the original GPG key from the site which distribute the packages. If you want to install the package w/o checking GPG signature (and warning) you can use command:

```
sudo yum localinstall --nogpgcheck  libffi-devel-3.0.13-19.el7.x86_64.rpm
```